# SQL: How to create result as shown below

Tags: sql

I facing issue with the below case:

I/P Table:

```
Column_1  Column_2
A             A 
B             B 
C             C
D             D
```

Cross Join will give me the below result

```
Actual O/P Value:
AA
AB--This combinati

on is Repeated
    AC
    AD

BA--This combination is Repeated
BB
BC
BD

CA
CB
CC
CD

DA
DB
DC
DD
```

Expected OP:

```
AA
AB
AC
AD

BB
BC
BD

CC
CD

DD
```

I dont want the combinations to be repeated:
Like AB and BA.

Comment: Can you tag the correct RDBMS? sql-server,mysql,...?

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra condition requiring the second value to be greater or equal to the first:

```
.... WHERE (Column_2 >= Column_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct least(column_1, column_2), greatest(column_1, column_2)
from ip_table 
   cross join ip_table
order by 1
```