# Removing "duplicate" groups in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get rid of duplicate groups in SQL, but the problem is they're not *really* duplicates.

I have a table like this:

```
a  |  b

0  |  1
2  |  3
```

however, the table also adds B, A back into it so I end up with this as the final table:

```
a  |  b

0  |  1
2  |  3
--------
1  |  0
3  |  2
```

What I'm trying to do is return the distinct pairs (the first table), and I'm having issues with it. Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: `1, 0` is not the same as `0, 1`.

Comment: Everything is distinct in your example. You cannot and will not get better answer than Gordon's.

Comment: This is more or less the same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14810824/330315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct (case when a < b then a else b end) as First,
       (case when a < b then b else a end) as Second
from t
```

If you are using Oracle (which is the assumption with SQLPlus), you can simplify this to:

```
select distinct least(a, b), greatest(a, b)
from t
```

Comment: Ah yes, this makes perfect sense. Thanks for the quick reply!